# Why a "private static" is not seen in a method?

Tags: java, static, field, private, visibility

I have a class with the following declaration of the fields:

```
public class Game {
private static String outputFileName;
....
}
```

I set the value of the `outputFileName` in the `main` method of the class.

I also have a `write` method in the class which use the `outputFileName`. I always call `write` after `main` sets value for `outputFileName`. But `write` still does not see the value of the `outputFileName`. It say that it's equal to `null`.

Could anybody, pleas, tell me what I am doing wrong?

**ADDED**
As it is requested I post more code:

In the main:

```
    String outputFileName = userName + "_" + year + "_" + month + "_" + day + "_" + hour + "_" + minute + "_" + second + "_" + millis + ".txt"; 
    f=new File(outputFileName);
        if(!f.exists()){
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }               
    System.out.println("IN THE MAIN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    System.out.println("------>" + outputFileName + "<------");
```

This line outputs me the name of the file.

Than in the `write` I have:

```
public static void write(String output) {
    // Open a file for appending.
    System.out.println("==========>" + outputFileName + "<============");
        ......
}
```

And it outputs null.

Comment: that should work fine, can you post more code please?

Comment: I guess it would be easier if you posted your full code. Trim it down to minimum file showing your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have a local variable or a parameter with the same name

Comment: You are right. I needed to remove `String` before the outputFileName in the `main` method. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

on the first line of your `main` code

```
String outputFileName = ...
```

needs to be

```
outputFileName = ...
```

otherwise you're making a new, local, var called outputFileName, and the `private static` one isn't getting touched.